# get the text from certain attribute using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I tried this code

```
reaction=soup.find_all('span',class_='1n9k')
```

and the result is

```
[<span class="_1n9k" data-hover="tooltip" tabindex="-1"><a ajaxify="/ufi/reaction/profile/dialog/ft_ent_identifier=ZmVlZGJhY2s6MzgyODczMjYzMDg5MTQy&amp;reaction_type=1&amp;av=0" aria-label="좋아요 17" class="_1n9l"href="/ufi/reaction/profile/browser/ft_ent_identifier=ZmVlZGJhY2s6MzgyODczMjYzMDg5MTQy&amp;av=0" rel="dialog" role="button" tabindex="0"><i class="sp_KIvjPBBBAwk sx_eaca68" role="img"></i></a></span>,<span class="_1n9k" data-hover="tooltip" tabindex="-1"><a ajaxify="/ufi/reaction/profile/dialog/?ft_ent_identifier=ZmVlZGJhY2s6MzgxNjk0Mjk2NTQwMzcy&amp;reaction_type=1&amp;av=0" aria-label="좋아요 55" class="_1n9l" href="/ufi/reaction/profile/browser/?ft_ent_identifier=ZmVlZGJhY2s6MzgxNjk0Mjk2NTQwMzcy&amp;av=0" rel="dialog" role="button" tabindex="0"><i class="sp_KIvjPBBBAwk sx_eaca68" role="img"></i></a></span>,<span class="_1n9k" data-hover="tooltip" tabindex="-1"><a ajaxify="/ufi/reaction/profile/dialog/ft_ent_identifier=ZmVlZGJhY2s6MzgxNjk0Mjk2NTQwMzcy&amp;reaction_type=2&amp;av=0" aria-label="최고예요 3" class="_1n9l"href="/ufi/reaction/profile/browser/ft_ent_identifier=ZmVlZGJhY2s6MzgxNjk0Mjk2NTQwMzcy&amp;av=0" rel="dialog" role="button" tabindex="-1"><i class="sp_KIvjPBBBAwk sx_b917e0" role="img"></i></a></span>]
```

I want to get the text in the attribute 'aria-label'. How could do this ?
I can't use 'find'.

And I want to know this answer if i use 'select'.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share URL?

Answer (score 2):

Just loop through the list and print the `aria-label` attribute of all `span` tags, like this:

```
for span in reaction:
    print(span.a['aria-label'])
```